# Sql Injection queries

Tags: sql, security, web, mysqli

I have a website which contains sql injection vulnerability but i can exploit it, just because of some filtration by the web server.

So i have a payload **order by 4** to find the columns but i can't find. I don't know whats happening but when i use this payload it works
**' order by 4--+** when this payload executes i get the column error.

**So what happens with the second one? The main doubt is what is the work of the  --+ and why is it necessary to put a single tick (') in second payload?**

Comment: Instead to gave negative vote try to gave answer,

Comment: worth reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: Ppl gave negative votes bcuz StackOverflow is for broken code you can ask this types of question in https://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `--` in sql means : comment what is forwarding.

You should use a ' to don't get **sql syntaxe errors** on your injection and to see the result.

If you use **PHP**, just take a look for [The Documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/security.database.sql-injection.php). Wish it could help you.

Good luck

Comment: @Utkarsh , Did this help ?

Comment: Hey, and just take a look [this post explaining how to prevent SQL injections in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

Comment: Yeah absolutely, and sorry! for not replying you.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to make this post as resolved !